# Zend Framework 2 Fileprg delete old files

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2

I am using Zend Framework 2 fileprg for uploading files. If form is invalid it uploads a file but after validation on second time it again uploads the file with different name. How to delete the old file uploaded previously on invalid form?

Answer (score 0):

Use **file_exists()** to Check whether a file or directory exists,and 
 the **unlink()** function to deletes the  file

Example :

```
   $filename = '/path/to/Images1.png';
    $Message = '';
    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        if (!unlink($filename)) {
            $Message = "Error deleting $filename";
        } else {
            $Message = "Deleted $filename";
        }
    } else {
        $Message = "The file $filename does not exist";
    }
     return $Message;
```